# Functions overlapping each other in Android

Tags: android, tabs, overlap, overlapping

I'm building an Android application and on my MainActivity I have a "switch" button and right below it I have a bar with three different tabs.

The switch button can be set in "on" and "off". It was the first thing I tried to do and it worked just fine. But after I added this bar with tabs the switch button stopped working, it appears to have something inside this bar that doesn't allow the switch to work. I am new to Android Development.

This is my MainActivity Code:

If I erase or comment everything from "//Tabs" bellow the switch starts to work again, otherwise it just doesn't change from on to off.

```
public class MainScreen  extends AppCompatActivity{

    Switch list_toggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        final TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml("Absent"));

        list_toggle = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
        list_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml("Available"));

                } else {

                    textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml("Absent"));

                }
            }
        });

        //Tabs

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Orders"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Past Orders"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("More"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/topbg"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/top_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Hi, Marcos"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:showText="true"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:thumb="@drawable/customswitchselector"
        android:track="@drawable/custom_track"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginRight="69dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:textColor="#a6a6a6"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mySwitch"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="149dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your XML, I think your problem is there.

Comment: I just added the xml to the post.

Comment: It seems that attributes for positioning in the RelativeLayout are missing. If that is the problem cutting the Switch and pasting it to the end of its RelativeLayout (making it the last child) should make it work. Can you try it?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not a good solution though. I will write an answer and explain there.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll be waiting then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `RelativeLayout` means that you position its child views *relatively* to each other. For example you may say that you want a `TabLayout` to appear below a `Switch`. To indicate the relation between two views these two atributes are used: `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_toRightOf`. With them you say I want this view to be below or to right of the view with the following resource ID. In your case this is how the layout of the `TabLayout` should look:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mySwitch">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="149dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that you are already doing the same relation between the `Switch` and the `Toolbar`.

There are other tags working with RelativeLayout (centering the view, or snapping it to the edge of the layout). If you don't provide any of those for a child view it will be drawn at the top left edge of the RelativeLayout by default. If there is already a view there, they would just be on top of each other. If you don't provide positioning information for any of your child views, all would be drawn snapped at the top left edge and can all overlap. Sometimes this is the behavior that we are looking for but not in your case. You did not add an attribute for the layout of the Tab section in your xml and Android deduced to just draw it on top of the Switch. So this layout got the touch events meant for the `Switch` and thatswhy it didn't work.

But why making the `Switch` the last child worked? Because the views are drawn in the order they are in the xml. So when the `Switch` is last, it is drawn last, after the RelativeLayout child and it is the one to be on top. This means it can get the touch events now. However, you can see how using the attributes is the better solution. They are actually made to address situations like yours and using the order of the children is kind of subtle.